# routing en0 to en1 (mac os x)

Tags: mac-osx, routing

I am in Mac OS X,
I have a raspberry(192.168.200.2) connected to en0 (192.168.200.1). 
I've my en1 with the network 192.168.1.0/24. I reach internet via this interface.

All the goes to 192.168.200.1

So, I would like to redirect all my packets from en0 to en1.

I have enable ip forwarding :

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

And i tried to redirect the en0 trafic to en1 via :

1) "system preference/internet sharing" -> it's not working

2)

```
ipfw add 1040 allow ip from any to any via en0
ipfw add divert natd all from any to any via en1
ipfw add pass all from any to any
natd -interface en1
```

Well, it's not working. And i'm lost.

So What i need to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would like your raspberry pi to be able to access the Internet using your wireless connection.

Using OS X, you should be able to open your Sharing preferences, select "Internet sharing", and then set "Share your connection from:" to "Wi-Fi" and set "To computers using:" to "Ethernet".  This will allow devices -- such as your raspberry pi -- connected to your ethernet port to access the internet via your wireless connection.

This will NAT devices attached to your ethernet port.  That is, connections from your raspberry pi will appear to come from your Mac's wireless ip address.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, it doesn't even ping en1 ip (192.168.1.17)...

Comment: Is your raspberry pi configured to acquire an ip address using dhcp? Is it *able* to acquire an address via dhcp?  Also, have you rebooted since making the sysctl and firewall changes?  Those are unnecessary and I don't know how they will interact with the internet sharing feature.

Comment: Yes raspberry has an ip (192.168.200.2), it pings en0 (192.168.200.1) when the firewall is off (when the mac firewall is on it doesn't ping).
No i didn't reboot after launch the commands.

Comment: In order to use the Internet Sharing feature, let it set everything up for you: do *not* manually configure packet forwarding, ipfw, or the raspberry's IP address. Internet Sharing will configure forwarding, ipfw, natd, named (DNS service for the private network), a new IP address on the private interface (generally 192.168.2.1/24), and dhcp service on the private interface.

Comment: Maxdiv: From you comment it's not clear if you're letting your pi acquire it's address from your Mac using DHCP.  As Gordon says, you need to let the Mac take care of ip address distribution.  You *should* probably reboot your system for the same reason to clear out any of the firewall changes you made by hand.

Comment: I tried what you said : reboot my mac, then active internet sharing. My en0 got 169.254.212.13 (APIPA address). So it doesn't work... I'm wondering why am I getting this address ?!

Comment: @Maxdiv: Check with the `ifconfig` command; the 192.168.2.1 address won't appear in the network preferences. The Mac's dhcp server won't serve to itself -- it's the raspberry that must be in dhcp mode, the Mac could be dhcp or static it doesn't matter.